# Reverse every k block of nodes in a link list

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I was trying to solve this problem of reversing every k block of nodes in a link list. I am processing 2*k elements in every outer while loop. Can it be done by just processing k elements in every outer while loop or without using hasknodes() function?

Sample input: 1->2->3->4->5 and k = 3

Sample output:3->2->1->4->5

```
 struct node *rev(struct node *head,int k)
    {
        if(k == 0 || k == 1) {
            return head;
        }
        int i;
        struct node *prev,*temp,*curr,*newhead,*p,*thead;
        p = head;
        thead = head;
        newhead = NULL;
        while(p && hasknodes(p,k)) {
            prev = NULL;
            curr = p;
            i = 0;
            while(curr && i < k) {
                temp = curr->next;
                curr->next = prev;
                prev = curr;
                curr= temp;
                i++;
            }
            if(newhead == NULL) {
                newhead = prev;
            }
            else {
                thead->next = prev;
            }
            p->next = curr;
            head = p;
            if(p) {
                p = p->next;
            }
        }
        if(newhead == NULL) {
            return head;
        }
        return newhead;
    }
//The function hasknodes(p,k) checks if there are k elements present from the current position p.
```

Comment: You dont have to know the remaining length, if you can undo the reversal of the last section.

Comment: Shoudn't the sample output be `2->1->4->3->5`?

Comment: Other restrictions?  can you use a vector as temporary?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie That was wrong. see the edit.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN we can't use vectors

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to call the function **hasknodes**; instead start picking up nodes and link them in reverse order (as you do in your inner while loop) and if you arrive at the end of the list prematurely, then re-append the elements of your reversed list. The disadvantage of this approach however is that the code gets a little more complicated.

As the first commenter wrote: O(2*n) is actually the same as O(n), because O(n) means that your problem can be solved in time *proportionally* to n. So, you are basically done already :-)

Comment: I see you referred to the first comment, but did not mention the second comment which you basically repeated in your answer

Comment: Re-appending will come at cost of extra memory I guess.

Comment: @shivam mitra: No, re-appending does not cost extra memory. It is just a matter of tweaking the node links.

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to think of reversing as popping from one list and pushing onto another.  You also need to know the tail of the previous block of k in order to append the next.  So in pseudocode:

```
// let list be the head of the input list
prev_tail = sentinel; // fake previous tail node to append the first block
while list is not NULL 
  tail = list
  block = NULL
  for k times and while list isn't NULL
    push(block, pop(list))
  prev_tail->next = block
  prev_tail = tail;
return sentinel->next;
```

Now in C, where the push and pop are implemented in the usual way:

```
typedef struct node_s { 
  struct node_s *next;
  ...
} Node;

Node *reverse_blocks(Node *list, int k) {
  Node sentinel[1] = {{NULL}};
  Node *prev_tail = sentinel;
  while (list) {
    Node *block = NULL;
    Node *tail = list;
    for (int i = 0; list && i < k; i++) {
      Node *pop = list;
      list = list->next;
      pop->next = block; // push(block, pop)
      block = pop;
    }
    prev_tail->next = block;
    prev_tail = tail;
  }
  return sentinel->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple recursive solution for this :

```
struct node *reverse (struct node *head, int k)
{
   struct node* current = head;
   struct node* next = NULL;
   struct node* prev = NULL;
   int count = 0;   

     /*reverse first k nodes of the linked list */
     while (current != NULL && count < k)
    {
       next  = current->next;
       current->next = prev;
       prev = current;
       current = next;
       count++;
    }

   /* next is now a pointer to (k+1)th node,Recursively call for the   
      list starting from current.And make rest of the list as next of first node */
   if(next !=  NULL)
   { 
       head->next = reverse(next, k); 
   }

   /* prev is new head of the input list */
   return prev;
}
```